# setNeedsDisplay does not call drawRect

Tags: drawrect

when my program starts for the first time, drawRect is automatically called and it prints the view.

When I call setNeedsDisplay, it does not call drawRect.

I have the IBOutlet correctly linked to the view and associated the view to the correct class.

thanks

Mohammed